# Links to CSS in another folder are broken when trying to host a simple site on Google Drive

Tags: google, web-hosting, html5

I have a simple website that I'd like to host on Google Drive. I have the contents separated into multiple folders, one for HTML, one for CSS, etc... and they're all stored in a main folder which I put up on Google Drive. I can open any individual page on the site, but links to CSS, JavaScript, videos, and even other HTML pages aren't working. I know it can be done, I did it a few months ago, but don't remember how, and I can't find any helpful online tutorials. If someone could explain to me how to do this, preferably without altering any of my code, that'd be great. If it matters, my current links to HTML in the same folder look like `example.html` and links to other folders look like `../OtherFolder/example.css`. Thanks!

Comment: Hosting websites on Google Drive was deprecated in August 2015 and will be removed after 31 August 2016. Reference: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to have an `index.html` as that file will be served when someone tries to access the homepage of your site. Second, Google Drive websites have a URL structure like `googledrive.com/host/` and there’s no way to change the default URL.

Further, make sure to change the sharing permissions to public, which generates the googledrive.com URL using the ID of the new folder.

Comment: "the ID of the **new folder**" - I think that's an important point... to share the _root folder_ that contains the website files, not the individual files in that folder, which is what the [Google Help Document](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en) appears to suggest.